# Why goes Golang URL lib always insert '://'?

Tags: go

In an URL, the authority is supposed to be optional, meaning that URLs such as `mailto:John.Doe@example.com` are valid.

In Golang 1.15.2, if using the `net/url` class to make an URL like above, it does not appear to allow creation of URLs without an authority.

E.g.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    var theURL = url.URL{}
    theURL.Scheme = "mailto"
    theURL.Path = "John.Doe@example.com"
    fmt.Println(theURL.String()) // should be mailto:John.Doe@example.com, but is mailto://John.Doe@example.com
}
```

Am I missing something here or is this technically a bug?

Comment: Definitely suggests it's a bug!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `theURL.Opaque` instead of `theURL.Path`. See  https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL

> URLs that do not start with a slash after the scheme are interpreted as:
>
> ```
> scheme:opaque[?query][#fragment]
> ```

Working code in Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/TFATDQu4PHc

Comment: Ah, I can see the logic now. It looks like `Path` is only useful for schemes where an authority is in use - so a little knowledge of the scheme is needed to know whether to work with `Path` or `Opaque`.